# Probabilities of bivariate normally distributed random variable

Tags: matlab, probability, normal-distribution

I'm trying to calculate the probability of a bivariate normal distribution over a specific area using Matlab.

Lets assume that the random variable  follows a standard normal distribution and I want to calculate the mass of the unit circle.

I used the following code:

```
fun = @(x,y) exp(-0.5*(x.^2+y.^2))/(2*pi);
ymin = @(x) -sqrt(1-(x.^2));
ymax = @(x) sqrt(1-(x.^2));
integral2(fun,-1,1,ymin,ymax)
```

I get 0.3935. I'm wondering that this result is correct.

Can anyone confirm that the result is correct or point on the mistake i made?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is correct. Some checks:

- Integrate on a large square and see if the result is almost `1`:

  ```
  >> integral2(fun,-5,5,-5,5)
  ans =
     0.999998853581851
  ```
- The 90-percentile of a univariate Gaussian distribution is

  ```
  >> norminv(.9)
  ans =
     1.281551565544601
  ```

  So, the integral of your function on `[−∞,∞] × [−∞,1.281]` should be `0.9`:

  ```
  >> integral2(fun,-10,10,-10,norminv(.9))
  ans =
     0.900000750806316
  ```
- The definitive, Monte Carlo check:

  ```
  >> N = 1e6;
  x = randn(1,N);
  y = randn(1,N);
  mean((x>-1)&(x<1)&(y>-sqrt(1-(x.^2)))&(y<sqrt(1-(x.^2))))
  ans =
     0.393678000000000
  ```